# Storing node module on S3 bucket for AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have developed a nodejs based function/program and want to run it on AWS Lambda. The problem is that the size is greater than 50MB and AWS Lambda supports direct function code to be under 50MB.

Mainly on my code the node module are of 43MB and the actual code is around 7MB. So is there any way I can separate my node module from code, May be if we can store the node modules in S3 bucket and then access it on AWS Lambda? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

P.S: Due to some dependencies issues I cant run this function as a Docker image on Lambda.

Comment: Which NPM packages are you importing that take up 43MB?

Comment: @jarmod I am not too sure because I have received this folder from developers who coded this.

Comment: The node_modules folder is presumably in your packaged ZIP file that you are failing to upload to AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want or cannot use Docker packaging, you can zip up your node_modules into an S3 bucket.

Your `handler` (or the module containing your handler), can then download the zip archive and extract files to `/tmp`. Then, you `require()` your modules from there.

The above description make not be 100% accurate as there are many ways of doing it. But that's the general idea.

This is one deployment method that `zappa`, a tool for deploying Python/Django apps to AWS Lambda, has supported long before docker containers were allowed in Lambda.

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/pull/548

Answer (score 1):

You may use [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) which is a perfect fit for your use case. Sometime ago, we need to use facebook sdk for one of our project and we created a lambda layer for the facebook sdk(32 mb) and then the deployment package became only 4 KB.

[It is stated as](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-lambda-layers-to-simplify-your-development-process/)

> Using layers can make it faster to deploy applications with the AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM) or the Serverless framework. By moving runtime dependencies from your function code to a layer, this can help `reduce the overall size of the archive` uploaded during a deployment.

Single Lambda function can use up to `five layers`. The maximum size of the total unzipped function and all layers is `250 MB` which is far beyond your limits.